# production.ERROR: Route [appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list] not defined in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In Laravel-5.8 application, a form is submitted and notification is submitted through:

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
'actionURL' => route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal', ['id'=>$userId]),
```

This correctly send notification:

[![notification][1]][1]

route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'appraisal', 'as' => 'appraisal.', 'namespace' => 'Appraisal', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('appraisal_goals/goal_review', 'AppraisalGoalsController@goal_review')->name('appraisal_goals.goal_review');
    Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_list', 'AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_list')->name('appraisal_goals.manager_employee_list');
    Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal/{id?}', 'AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal')->name('appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal');
    Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal_list/{id?}', 'AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal_list')->name('aappraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list');
});
```

manager_employee_goal.blade

```html
<td>
  @if(in_array($goal->is_approved, [1, 2, 3]))
  <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list', ['id'=>$goal->id]) }}">
                                        {{ trans('global.view') }}
                                    </a> @endif @if(in_array($goal->is_approved, [1]))
  <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comment{{ $goal->id }}" data-original-title="Comment">Comment</a> @endif
</td>
```

When the user clicks on the button on the notification as shown in the diagram, it suppose to redirect to:

> ```
> Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal/{id?}', 'AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal')->name('appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal');
> ```

But I got error 500 and the browser url has:

> http://localhost:8888/myapp/appraisal/appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal/470

The the Log has this error:

> 2020-10-22 17:29:51] production.ERROR: Route [appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\pmyapp\resources\views\appraisal\appraisal_goals\manager_employee_goal.blade.php) {"userId":469,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Route [appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp
> esources\views\appraisal\appraisal_goals\manager_employee_goal.blade.php) at C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:388, InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Route [appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list] not defined. at C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:388)

I didn't call:

> appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list

Why is it coming up and how do I resolve this error?

Thanks

Comment: Try with `php artisan route:clear` `php aryisan view:clear` then check the route list `php artisan route:list`

Comment: I got the solution through route:list. Though I had tried several time and never observed.   I have aappraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list instead of appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list.   aa at the begining instead of a. Thanks